# View people check-ins for Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-pages

Our business wants to reward people who check in to our Facebook place on Facebook.

Our Facebook page insights shows demographic data for people who checked in, but not the people themselves.  This means I can't contact people with a reward.

Do you know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Facebook app for that, and ask users to add that granting you permissions to send them the feed/mail notification for rewards. Facebook only offers geographic and demographic data through insight. and no details will be revealed according to their privacy policies.